# React-table move custom filter outsite the table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

### Help me please move custom filter outside the table, cuz he work only inside header block.

**TableContainer:**

```
<table {...getTableProps()}>
            <thead>
                {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
                    <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                        {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                            <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>
                                {column.render("Header")}
                                <Filter column={column} />
                            </th>
                        ))}
                    </tr>
                ))}
            </thead>
            <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
                {rows.map((row, i) => {
                    prepareRow(row);
                    return (
                        <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                            {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                                return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render("Cell")}</td>;
                            })}
                        </tr>
                    );
                })}
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

**Custom filter:**

```
export const Filter = ({ column }) => {
    return (
        <div className="Filter" style={{ marginTop: 5 }}>
            {column.canFilter && column.render("Filter")}
        </div>
    );
};
```

[Here is full code of Filter ...](https://pastebin.com/i6SY8UxQ)

Based on this code: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-filter-by-date-range-forked-fcwtg5?file=/src/filters.js)

Screenshot:
[click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1ApI.png)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I think, you need to adjust some css for that. may be position absolute and margin top to some value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Filter UI uses a controlled **input** tag that the `value` bound to the **filterValue** state and the `onChange` event bound to a function that sets the filter value by using **setFilter** setter. Both filterValue and setFilter are only available when we use **useFilters** plugin hook and can be rendered both inside and outside the table.

1. **Inside table head**; It receives filter state and setter of table instance from [Filter](https://react-table-v7.tanstack.com/docs/api/useFilters#column-options) option at column definition.

```
  // Filter UI
  function ColumnFilter({
    column: { filterValue, _preFilteredRows, setFilter },
  }) {
    return (
      <input
        value={filterValue || ""}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setFilter(e.target.value || undefined);
        }}
        placeholder={`Search records...`}
      />
    );
  }
```

```
  // Column  definition
  const columns = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: "Country",
        accessor: "country",
        Filter: ColumnFilter,
      },
      ...
    ]
  )
```

2. **Outside the table**: Both filter state and setter are destructured from [table instance](https://react-table-v7.tanstack.com/docs/api/useFilters#instance-properties) of **useTable** hook.

```
  // Filter UI
  function SearchBox({ filterValue, setFilter }) {
    return (
      <input
        value={filterValue || ""}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setFilter(e.target.value || undefined);
        }}
        placeholder={`Search records...`}
      />
    );
  }
```

```
  // tableInstance from useTable hook
  const {
    ...
    setFilter,
    state: { filters },
  } = useTable(
    {
      columns,
      data,
    },
    useFilters
  );

  return (
    <>
      <SearchBox
        filterValue={filters[0].value}
        setFilter={setFilter}
      </SearchBox>
      <Table data={data} columns={columns} />
    </>
  )
```

So, if you want to move the filter outside the table head, just modified your code by following the above concept.

Comment: So, i have a dropdown instead of search but issue is my dropdown option has value such as 'yes', 'yes, on notice' .Whenever yes is selected it shows both rather than just yes. Any idea how i can change that. Thanks